# How to prevent User-Agent: Eureka/1 to return source code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mono, bundling-and-minification

ASP.NET Mono MVC 4 application uses MVC4 built in bundling and minification for css and js files.

If user agent string in request is changed to Eureka/1 using fiddler

```
User-Agent: Eureka/1
```

and request is re-issued, whole source code with all comments are sent to client.

How to prevent this so that comments in source code code cannot inspected by client ?

Source:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/728146/ASP-NET-MVC-bundles-internals

I tried to add `debug='false'` to `web.config` but problem persists.

Comment: Bundling and minification are optimization techniques, not a security measure. Are the comments really an issue for you?

Comment: Yes. I want not to allow see comments in css and js files in any way. How to implement this ?

Comment: @Andrus I wasn't aware of this "feature".... I wonder why they would even put this in there?

Comment: This is related to https://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/workitem/137 and https://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/workitem/136

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to remove comments by creating a classes that inherit from `IBundleBuilder`. This is written for [Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework 1.1.3](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/) which was updated on 2/20/2014:

```
public class ScriptBundleBuilder : IBundleBuilder
{
    public virtual string BuildBundleContent(Bundle bundle, BundleContext context, IEnumerable<BundleFile> files)
    {
        var content = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(file.VirtualFile.VirtualPath));
            Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.CodeSettings settings = new Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.CodeSettings();
            settings.RemoveUnneededCode = true;
            settings.StripDebugStatements = true;
            settings.PreserveImportantComments = false;
            settings.TermSemicolons = true;
            var minifier = new Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.Minifier();
            content.Append(minifier.MinifyJavaScript(Read(f), settings));
        }

        return content.ToString();
    }

    private string Read(FileInfo file)
    {
        using (var r = file.OpenText())
        {
            return r.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
} 

public class StyleBundleBuilder : IBundleBuilder
{
    public virtual string BuildBundleContent(Bundle bundle, BundleContext context, IEnumerable<BundleFile> files)
    {
        var content = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var file in files)
        {   
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(file.VirtualFile.VirtualPath));
            Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.CssSettings settings = new Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.CssSettings();
            settings.CommentMode = Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.CssComment.None;
            var minifier = new Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.Minifier();
            content.Append(minifier.MinifyStyleSheet(Read(f), settings));
        }

        return content.ToString();
    }

    private string Read(FileInfo file)
    {
        using (var r = file.OpenText())
        {
            return r.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

And then telling the bundle to use this builder. This example is for a StyleBundle:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    var bundle = new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css");
    bundle.Builder = new StyleBundleBuilder();
    bundle.Include("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
        //etc
        );
    bundles.Add(bundle);

    var scriptBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr");
    scriptBundle.Builder = new ScriptBundleBuilder();
    scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/modernizr-*");
    bundles.Add(scriptBundle);

    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; //for testing
}
```

This was tested/confirmed in Chrome by changing the user-agent to `Eureka/1.0`.

For at least some previous versions of the Web Optimization framework (1.0 and prior I think), the only difference was the final parameter. So it would look like `public virtual string BuildBundleContent(Bundle bundle, BundleContext context, IEnumerable<FileInfo> files)` and requires only minor changes to make work... though you're likely better off just updating.

Concerning this problem and one brought up [in another recent SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22383478/1810243) about how licensing information gets stripped out during minification... I made [a NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LicensedBundler/) to address these issues.

Comment: This outputs `/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(1,177643): run-time error CSS1062: Expected semicolon or closing curly-brace, found '/'
 */
` to start of minified css file. It looks like minification is tried two times. How to remove this error from output?

Comment: @Andrus do you not get that error with regular minification (without using the Builder)? That error can happen under normal circumstances depending on your style sheets.

Comment: How to make it work for js files also ? I tried `Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JsSettings settings` but JsSettings property does not exist

Comment: @Andrus OK give me a second I will update for JS and also for the new 1.1.3 version. I couldn't replicate your issue even after including previously minified files. It could problem with your original files. Sometimes updating the Optimization package fixes these issues.

Comment: @Andrus updated. You'd need to update the Package as well as the 3rd param changed.

Comment: Adding `content.Append(";")` to end of for loop fixes my error. Your code concatenates files without adding separator. Maybe to merge both classes into single one with two methods, there is code duplication

Comment: @Andrus You are correct about the separator -- sorry I didn't notice. I updated answer with `settings.TermSemicolons = true;` which fixes as well. As for code duplication, yes that "Read" method is in both just to make this copy/pastable for someone for scripts or styles, and should be separated out to a centralized location.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is regarding changing the behaviour of the bundle process in MVC, but as an alternative, you could create build/deploy scripts that minify your CSS/JS before being published.  You could use some of the applications in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520285/is-there-a-good-javascript-minifier)